# Feature history of windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am preparing a Windows BAT script that uses some new features like `setlocal` and  group of commands in FOR loops like

```
for %%a in (a b c) do (
   del %%a.bak
   ren %%.a %%a.bak
)
```

I would like to know when the individual features have been introduced. So I could see, if such a BAT script is compatible with e.g. Windows XP, Windows 7, or Windows 8.1.

**Edit:**

The FOR command ist pretty old. I am curious about the command grouping  syntax with the round parentheses.

But there are others features. e.g. call of a function inside a BAT script. It doesn't make sense to ask for each individual feature. That's why I asked for the history.

Answer (score 1):

Setlocal/endlocal and the FOR syntax have been present since at least 1996. Windows NT 4 (July 1996) included them and most, if not all of what we see today. The biggest changes since then came with Windows 2000 (December 1999). Just one example: at that time an additional pair of switches is available for setlocal: ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION / DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION. A script which runs in NT4 should run in every NT family OS since (2000, XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, and Windows 10, plus Server 2003 to 2016). Rob van der Woude's scripting pages include a list of commands including information about which OS in which they first appeared. You could use this to ensure backward compatibility.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchcommands.php

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't say anything about history of commands, so I turned to
the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) and searched for dates of saved documentation.

The Wayback Machine seemed to do badly with Microsoft links, so I searched in
the [ss64.com documentation](https://ss64.com/).

For the `setlocal` command, the earliest page instance for
[setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
was recorded on the Wayback Machine on February 2003.

For the `FOR` command, the earliest page instance for
[FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
was also recorded on the Wayback Machine on February 2003.

These features then seem to date from at least Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.

I tested both commands in an XP virtual machine and they worked flawlessly.
I don't have access to earlier versions of Windows, but I think that XP
is early enough for your purposes.